# OpenOPC on Windows: Clas not registered

Tags: python, com, windows-7-x64, opc

I'm having problems with OpenOPC library (OpenOPC-1.2.0.win32-py2.7) on Windows 7 64bit machine.

```
>>> import OpenOPC
>>> i =OpenOPC.client()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "OpenOPC.py", line 170, in __init__
    raise OPCError, error_msg
OpenOPC.OPCError: Dispatch: Class not registered.
```

What could be the cause of this error? My command line opc client works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Class not registered error** is due to wrong OPC server class ID or the OPC server not exists.

Comment: OPC server exists. I can connect via OpenOPC Gateway Service and then probe existing servers. I understand this problem is related to COM/DCOM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- install python 2.7 **32bit** version at C:\Python27
- install [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) **32bit** version
- install [OpenOPC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openopc/files/)